# Is it possible to use Entity Framework to express a MERGE with logic?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, upsert

I've got a MERGE statement like the following:

```
MERGE 
    MyTable AS target
USING     
    (SELECT @Id, @Name, @Description, @Checksum)
    AS source(Id, Name, Description, Checksum)
ON 
    target.Id = source.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET
    Name=@Name, 
    Description=@Description,
    IsChanged=(select case 
               when target.Checksum=@Checksum
                 then 0
                 else 1
               end),
    checksum=@checksum
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Id, Name, Description, IsChanged, Checksum)
    VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Description, 0, @Checksum);
```

This is a very simple merge, except that I'm computing a checksum for the record, and I also want to flag the `IsChanged` field on the record based on whether the checksum has changed, which depends on the data in the target table.

This works perfectly, but now I'm considering migrating this to Entity Framework, and I'd like to use an AddObject/Attach syntax with a .NET object. Is it possible to do this, but capture the server side logic based on the target table data?